# Can't add objects to scene

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, blend-files

I'm doing a really basic outline of a park scene, and i'm trying to add a circular plane so I can begin to model my amphitheater. For some reason, when I hit 'Space' and add the circle, nothing shows up. Same for appending an object. I have also tried centering it with Shift+W.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/vv56l2ono53f28z/Park_Project.blend

Here is the link to the .blend file. I need as much help as possible; I have a project including this I need to turn in tomorrow. Thanks for any help or insight.

Comment: Nothing like a little procrastination . . .

Comment: This was the last part to my project. There are over 20 pages of papers I completed beforehand, along with a powerpoint and some zoning laws stuff.

Comment: In your scene you have two layers 1 and 9. Newly created objects are going to 9. To make layer 1 the active layer press 1

Comment: how do I delete the layer?

Comment: By moving your object to a different layer (or deleting all the objects on the layer)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the active layer is not the one that is visible. So your objects are being created in layer 9 instead of layer 1.

[image]

To make layer one be the active layer press <kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

To see the contents of both layers press <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd>